# I can ping server by name but can't map drive to it

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, networking, active-directory, windows-xp

I'm having an issue with a laptop (Windows XP SP3, member of a domain) where I can ping one of our file servers (Windows Server 2003) by IP address and by name, but if I try to map a drive to a folder on that server, it doesn't work. It used to work, but we've made some network changes this weekend (added a server, changed IP addresses), and now I can't get it to work. All of our other computers have been able to connect since the change; this is the only one having this problem. Any ideas as to why this might be happening? Thanks.

EDIT: Note that I CAN map the drive if I use the IP address, just not the server name. But I need to get the server name to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with name resolution. Check the following:

1. Hosts file in C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
2. LMHosts file in C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\lmhosts
3. DNS Server. Open up DNS Management, Right click on server, go to Scavenge Resource Records. Now restart netlogon service on file server, DC, and client

Then try again.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I just tried this and it didn't clear up the problem. I also forgot to mention that I CAN map the drive if I use the IP address, but I need to be able to do it with the server name also.

Comment: Have you checked your DNS server settings on the client and dns records on the dns server?

Comment: Yes, and they seem correct, however there is no PTR record for this computer in the Reverse Lookup Zone in DNS. There are PTR records for the other users in the office. Could that be it? Should I just add a PTR record? Also, using Wireshark, I see that when I try to map the drive using the IP address, the computer first sends 4 packets to the correct IP address. But when I use the server name, it sends the 4 packets to the wrong IP address. That must be the problem, but where is it getting that IP address from? I can't find it in any DNS record or in the hosts file.

Comment: Wouldn't be the PTR record. Did you check the lmhosts file as well?

Comment: That IP address that it's using is the OLD IP address of the server. But when I look at the local DNS cache, it shows the correct (new) IP address for that server. And I can ping the server fine. Why is it pulling up this old address only when I try to map a drive?

Comment: I may be off target here but have you checked the WINS servers on the client machine? DNS and WINS seem the likely culprits here.

Comment: I think you found it! I just checked the lmhosts file, which I didn't even think was being used, and there were the old addresses. I'm not quite sure how to deal with it though. Should I just delete/rename lmhosts and then reboot?

Comment: Jason, thanks so much. That fixed my problem. Should you edit your answer to add the lmhosts solution, so I can mark it answered? Or add a new answer.

Comment: To clarify, it's not the lmhosts.sam file; that's just a sample that doesn't do anything. It's the lmhosts file itself that I had to change/delete.

Comment: @johnnyb10, Thanks. It's been a while since I've messed with lmhosts, so I was just going off what was on my computer. It's fixed now.